# DrRacket - Find Largest Number in a set

Tags: racket

```
(for judges ([judge1 judge2 judge3 judge4 judge5 judge6 judge7 judge8])
    (define i 0)
    (define j 1)
    (cond [(< judges[i] judges[j])
           (cond [(equal?  judges[j] judges(length))
           (define highest-score judges[j])]
                 [else
                  (judges[i] judges[j])
                  (judges[j] judges[j +1])])]
          [else
           (cond [(equal? judges[i] judges[length -1])
                 (define highest-score judges[i])]
                 [else
                  (judges[j] judges[j +1])])]))
```

I want to be able to find the largest number in a set of values, which for this problem includes values from `judge1, judge2... judge8`. The way I'm trying to solve this problem is by taking the first two numbers on a list and comparing them; I can't seem to find much on DrRacket documentation on proper syntax for the type of operation I want to perform.

Comment: See [sort](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=sort#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29).

Comment: This looks like `racket` but it isn't. `for` takes different expressions. `define` makes a new local variable and it doesn't survive outside of the `for`. `judges[j]` is two expressions. The evaluation of the variable `jusdges` and a call to the function `j`. `()` and `[]` are the same. `[+ 1 2] ; ==> 3`. `[j] ; ==> ?` Vectors use `vector-ref` to access elements. How is the set of values? Is it a list or a vector?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way (in terms of writing code) to find the the maximum element is to sort the list, and grab the last element of that list. As @pdoherty926 mentioned, the easiest way to sort a list in Racket is with the [`sort`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=sort#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29) function. You just give it a list and a comparitor, and it sorts the list for you:

```
> (sort '(5 2 6 1) <)
'(1 2 5 6)
```

And since you want the `max` value just grab the last element:

```
> (last (sort '(5 2 6 1) <))
6
```

Although if you want to find the maximum value of other (non-list) data structures, [`for`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%29%29) is an attractive option. While your algorithm looks good, your syntax is off. In this particular case, I would actually recommend using [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Ffold#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29). Basically, it lets you have an accumulator, which will hold your highest judge so far, as well as the list of judges you are iterating through, and the body for how you want to modify the accumulator. In this case, your loop will look something like:

```
;; A judge is a non-negative number
(define judges '(5 6 1 2))
(for/fold ([largest -1])
          ([j (in-list judges)])
  ...)
```

Where you replace the `...` with the next value for `largest`. The entire loop evaluates to the final value for `largest`.

The interesting thing here is that `j` is an actual judge, not just an index to the `judges` list. So your body does *not* need to refer to the `judges` list at all. It should look something like:

```
(max j largest)
```

Since a judge is just a number. I will leave you to put the body in the loop as an exercise.

As an aside, since judges are just numbers, you can just use [`max`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=max#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._max%29%29) directly with [`apply`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
> (apply max '(5 6 1 2))
6
```

As one additional note, if for some reason you do want the actual index of the current judge you are examining, you can use [`in-naturals`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html?q=in-naturals#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-naturals%29%29):

```
(for/fold ([largest -1])
          ([j (in-list judges)]
           [index (in-naturals)])
  ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following recursive function also works to find largest number in a list:

```
(define (largestnum slist)
  (cond
    ((= (length slist) 2)      ; if only 2 numbers, compare them
     (if (> (car slist) (list-ref slist 1))
         (car slist)
         (list-ref slist 1)))
    (else                      ; else recurse to compare car with largest of cdr
     (let ((cdrLargest (largestnum (cdr slist))))
       (if (> (car slist) cdrLargest)
           (car slist)
           cdrLargest)))))


(define judges '(5 6 1 2))
(largestnum judges)
```

Output:

```
6
```